# Bernoulli distribution and Normal distribution, which is more closer to uniform distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions

For Bernoulli and normal distribution, I'm wondering which distribution is more closer to uniform distribution.

Is there any notion of similarity between two probability distributions?
If so, is that a proper way to know which distribution is more closer to some distribution?

For simplicity, everything here is discretized.

Since I do not know the criteria for this situation, any answers from any aspects are welcome:)

Comment: The Bernoulli distribution only has two discrete values. The normal distribution is continuous.

Comment: Thanks. I added additional assumption to make things easier.

Comment: The normal distribution still has an infinite number of values. Perhaps you meant the binomial distribution instead of the Bernoulli distribution?